# Set zlim in matplotlib scatter3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, scatter3d

I have three lists xs, ys, zs of data points in Python and I am trying to create a 3d plot with `matplotlib` using the `scatter3d` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')  
plt.xlim(290)  
plt.ylim(301)  
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)  
plt.savefig('dateiname.png')
plt.close()
```

The `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` work fine, but I don't find a function to set the borders in z-direction. How can I do so?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply use the `set_zlim` function of the `axes` object (like you already did with `set_zlabel`, which also isn't available as `plt.zlabel`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.random.random(10)
ys = np.random.random(10)
zs = np.random.random(10)

fig = plt.figure()  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')  
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)  
ax.set_zlim(-10, 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `plt.zlim` not implemented? That would make mpl more consistent and people would not have to ask this question here.

Comment: @Sören. 3D plotting is an extension. That being said, I don't see any reason why you can't have the relevant import set up an addition function in the plt namespace